# I am trying to automate homepage of paytm using jest-puppeteer but test is getting failed with out any error. And getting passed with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer, ui-testing, jest-puppeteer

The scenario is like:
Go to : https://paytm.com/
Click on signup button [frame window will be opened]
click on watchVideo button
click on close button
close the frame by clicking on X button.
note: When I am running on puppeteer it is getting passed. But when i am using jest-puppeteer it is executing each line of code but result is failed. i.e test is getting failed without any error.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your code in your question?

Comment: Please find the github link for your reference.

Comment: https://github.com/sumit-jain-321/jest-puppeteer.git